# *The parameters (number[],String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.* *Invalid email: d * *DNS error: http://m*

Tags: google-apps-script, rhino, rhino3d

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen()

{

var menu = [

             {name: "Send Wishes", functionName: "birthdayReminders"}

           ];

            ss.addMenu("Birthday Wishes", menu); 

}

function birthdayReminders()

{

var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

var subject = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();

var message = sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();

var bday = sheet.getRange("D:D").getValues();

var emailStatus = sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues();

var currentDate = new Date();

var sheetLength = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

var str = currentDate.toString();

var res = str.slice(0, 10);

var birthdayImage = sheet.getRange("F:F").getValues();

var imageLoaddata;

try

{

  var j=0;
  
  for (var i=1; i<birthdayImage.length; i++)

  {

    if(!(birthdayImage[i]== "" || birthdayImage[i]== "undefined" || birthdayImage[i]== "null"))

  {

   imageLoaddata = UrlFetchApp

                   .fetch(birthdayImage[i])

                   .getBlob()

                   .setName("imageLoad");

   j++; 

   console.log("image data " +i+imageLoaddata)

  }

else

  {

          console.log("image data first empty else " +i)

  }

  }
  
var k =1;

for(var i=1; i<bday.length; i++)

  {

    console.log("image data  second for" +i+birthdayImage[i]) 

  if (res == bday[i].toString().slice(0,10) && emailStatus[i] != "EMAIL_SENT")

    {

     var imageLoad;

       if(!(birthdayImage[i]== "" || birthdayImage[i]== "undefined" || birthdayImage[i]== "null"))

    {

      console.log("sdsdsdinside");

      imageLoad = UrlFetchApp

                          .fetch(birthdayImage[i])

                          .getBlob()

                          .setName("imageLoad");

      console.log("sdsdsd"+imageLoad);

       }

      else

{
    
     imageLoad = UrlFetchApp
  
                        .fetch(birthdayImage[k])

                        .getBlob()

                        .setName("imageLoad");
   
        k++;

        if(k>j)
       
       {

          k=1;
       
       }
      
}
                          
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress[i], subject[i],"",
                       
 { htmlBody:message[i] +"<BR><BR>"+ "<img src='cid:nlFlag'><BR><BR>Thanks<BR>Hr Team<BR>LatentView",

                      inlineImages:

                      {

                        nlFlag: imageLoad

                      }
});

        sheet.getRange(1 + i, 5).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");

        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 
    }

  }

 }

  catch(e)

  {

    Logger.log(MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@yyy.com", "Birthday Reminder-Delivery Failure ", "Your automatic birthday reminder email failed to send email due to :"+ e));

  }

}
```

The above is the Google app script to send an automated birthday email to our employees as we use Google Workspace mail service. The script was working fine for more than a year and since April it is not working.

Got a notification in the App script window that this script has been successfully migrated from Rhino to V8 runtime on Apr 20, 2023

I have seen the solution in this forum for this error "**The parameters (number[],String,String,(class)) don't match  the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.**" that the getValues to be changed to getValue.

I tried changing from var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
to var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValue(); but got an error as below.

**Your automatic birthday reminder email failed to send email due
to :Exception: Invalid email: d**

Later changed the getValues to getValue in the entire code and got an error as below.

**Your automatic birthday reminder email failed to send email due
to :Exception: DNS error: http://m**

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello all, Any suggestions or thoughts to fix the above error

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
```

returns a 2D array of rows and one columns from your spreadsheet.

So change:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress[i], subject[i],"",{ htmlBody:message[i] +
```

To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress[i][0], subject[i][0],"",{ htmlBody:message[i][0] +
```

You may need to do this in other places of your code but this one was obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have made the changes as you suggested but still getting the same below error after executing the script.

Your automatic birthday reminder email failed to send email due to :Exception: DNS error: http://m

Comment: Kindly advise if anywhere else in the code needs to be modified.

This code is written on Google sheet Apps Script. Below are the row headers of the Google sheet and its input value 

EmailAddress Subject Message          BirthdayDate Status    ImageURL  
xxx@yyy.com   HBD         Wish you HDB 13-06-2023 EMAIL_SENT   [URL of the picture]

You can also try executing this code from your personal gmail and let me know what needs to be corrected to send the birthday automated email.

Comment: Could anyone share your thoughts to fix this issue? Many thanks in advance.